# Python 3.6 - Resizing Tkinter Buttons In Accordance With Frame Size

Tags: python, tkinter

I have been looking around on stack overflow for ages trying to find the answer to this but I just can't get anything to work, therefore I am asking this question. I have a little program with three buttons and a label, and they are in a grid. I was wondering how no matter the size or shape the buttons and label would stay the same relative to the frame. Similar to if I resized an image, everything stays the same size.

Here is my code:

```
from tkinter import *

class Window(Frame): #All the stuff for the GUI
   def __init__(self, master = None):
      Frame.__init__(self, master)
      self.master = master
      self.init_window()
      self.grid()

   def init_window(self):
      self.master.title("EncryptDecrypt")
      self.pack(fill = BOTH, expand = 1)

      quitButton = Button(self, text = "Quit", command = self.client_exit, width = 10, height = 5) #Quit Button
      quitButton.grid(row = 0, column = 0, sticky = W)

      encryptModeButton = Button(self, text = "Encrypt", command = lambda: self.execute("decrypted.txt", "encrypted.txt", 1, 0), width = 10, height = 5) #Encrypt Button
      encryptModeButton.grid(row = 0, column = 1, sticky = W)

      decryptModeButton = Button(self, text = "Decrypt", command = lambda: self.execute("encrypted.txt", "decrypted.txt", 0, 1), width = 10, height = 5) #Decrypt button
      decryptModeButton.grid(row = 0, column = 2, sticky = W)

      myLabel = Label(self, text = "Select The Action You Wish To Undertake", font = ("Purisa", 15))
      myLabel.grid(row = 0, column = 3) 
root = Tk()
root.geometry("610x80")

app = Window(root)   
root.mainloop()
```

Sorry if the answer is obvious, I have already tried `pack()`

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're asking. Are you saying that if you resize the window to be larger, you want everything to grow?

Comment: @BryanOakley Yes that is correct

Answer (score 4):

[There's a good tutorial to grid packer](http://www.tkdocs.com/tutorial/grid.html). Just scroll over "Handling Resize" and you would notice how to use `sticky` option and configure `weight` of column/row pair.

So let's try your example with `grid` packer:

```
from tkinter import *

class Window(Frame): #All the stuff for the GUI
   def __init__(self, master = None):
      Frame.__init__(self, master)
      self.master = master
      self.master.minsize(width=650, height=80)
      self.configure(relief=RAISED, borderwidth=10)
      self.init_window()
      self.grid(sticky = NSEW)

   def init_window(self):
      self.master.title("EncryptDecrypt")
      # configure weights; note: that action need for each container!
      self.master.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
      self.master.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
      self.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
      for i in range(4):
        self.columnconfigure(i, weight=1)

      quitButton = Button(self, text = "Quit", width = 10, height = 5) #Quit Button
      quitButton.grid(row = 0, column = 0, sticky = NSEW)

      encryptModeButton = Button(self, text = "Encrypt", width = 10, height = 5) #Encrypt Button
      encryptModeButton.grid(row = 0, column = 1, sticky = NSEW)

      decryptModeButton = Button(self, text = "Decrypt", width = 10, height = 5) #Decrypt button
      decryptModeButton.grid(row = 0, column = 2, sticky = NSEW)

      myLabel = Label(self, text = "Select The Action You Wish To Undertake", font = ("Purisa", 15))
      myLabel.grid(row = 0, column = 3, sticky = NSEW)



root = Tk()
root.geometry("650x80")

app = Window(root)
root.mainloop()
```

As you see - I just added a `sticky=NSEW` and `columnconfigure`/`rowconfigure` and seems like it works like you wish!
The weak side of this is the need to configure each container!

But here, in `pack` manager, there're more intuitive and performing the same role options - `fill` and `expand`!

```
from tkinter import *

class Window(Frame): #All the stuff for the GUI
   def __init__(self, master = None):
      Frame.__init__(self, master)
      self.master = master
      self.master.minsize(width=650, height=80)
      self.configure(relief=RAISED, borderwidth=10)
      self.init_window()
      self.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=True)

   def init_window(self):
      self.master.title("EncryptDecrypt")

      quitButton = Button(self, text = "Quit", width = 10, height = 5) #Quit Button
      quitButton.pack(fill=BOTH, side=LEFT, expand=True)

      encryptModeButton = Button(self, text = "Encrypt", width = 10, height = 5) #Encrypt Button
      encryptModeButton.pack(fill=BOTH, side=LEFT, expand=True)

      decryptModeButton = Button(self, text = "Decrypt", width = 10, height = 5) #Decrypt button
      decryptModeButton.pack(fill=BOTH, side=LEFT, expand=True)

      myLabel = Label(self, text = "Select The Action You Wish To Undertake", font = ("Purisa", 15))
      myLabel.pack(fill=BOTH, side=LEFT, expand=True)



root = Tk()
root.geometry("650x80")

app = Window(root)
root.mainloop()
```

What to use is your choice!
And there're a good topic about resizing, grid and pack! [Take a look](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14946963/tkinter-grid-how-to-position-widgets-so-they-are-not-stuck-together)

Some other useful links:

- [Tkinter Geometry Managers](http://effbot.org/zone/tkinter-geometry.htm)
- [Grid Geometry Manager](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/grid.htm)
- [grid columnconfigure](http://wiki.tcl.tk/9903)
- [grid rowconfigure](http://wiki.tcl.tk/9909)