# Python tkinter set text widget to bottom of window using grid

Tags: python, tkinter

I am totally new to using tkinter and am playing around with grid currently. I have set my window to be 1000x500 and have an image at the top left like this...

```
window = Tk()
window.geometry("1000x500") #Width x Height

logo = PhotoImage(file="logo.gif")
Label (window, image=logo, bg="#f0f0f0") .grid(row=0, column=0)

T = Text(window, height=2, width=30)
T.insert(END, "Just a text Widget\nin two lines\n")
T.grid(row=2, column=0)
```

I would like the text widget to be placed at the bottom of the window, I have tried setting the row to something larger but it doesn't have any effect.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: ***Where am I going wrong?***: Your Row 1 is empty, therefore the Layout Manager uses a height of 0. Read [python-3-6-resizing-tkinter-buttons-in-accordance-with-frame-size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42938090)

Answer (score 2):

Apparently,The easiest way is to use `.pack()` instead of `.grid()`.But if you really want to use `.grid()`.You need to set the `rowconfigure()` to set the weight of row,And `sticky="s"` or `sticky=S` to make it in the bottom.

Your code can be:

```
from tkinter import *

window = Tk()
# window.geometry("1000x500") #Width x Height

logo = PhotoImage(file="xxx")
Label (window, image=logo, bg="#f0f0f0") .grid(row=0, column=0)

T = Text(window, height=2, width=30)
T.insert(END, "Just a text Widget\nin two lines\n")
T.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=S)

window.grid_rowconfigure(1,weight=1)

window.mainloop()
```

Remember,if you want to always make it in the bottom and only use `.gird()`,you need to set the row weight of the text.So I suggest you put all the widget(except the Text widget in the bottom) in a `Frame`.And use `.grid()` in the `Frame`.The `Frame` and the `Text` use `.pack()`.

Comment: Have you proven that? I feel that's not what the OP wants. Rethink your last sentence, you can't use two Layout Manager, or rephrase to make clear what you mean.

Comment: I mean,if he wants to use two types of Layout manager,he can use a frame to put his widget in `frame`(in the frame,All of his widget can use `.grid()`),and the frame could use `.pack()`.

Comment: @stovfl: you can mix `grid` and `pack` in an application, just not with widgets that share the same parent/master. The suggestion in this answer is a valid suggestion.