# Tkinter layout Issues

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm having trouble making the layout the way I want it to be. I'm relatively new to this module and it doesn't feel very flexible, unless I'm just using these functions wrong. I've tried using frames with pack, frames with grid, grids without frames, and pack without frames. Packing felt very similar to float in CSS  but at the same time it didn't.

```
root = Tk()
root.title("Derivative Calculator GUI")

input = Entry(bg="white")
input.grid(row=0, column=0)
derivbutton = Button(text="Derive This")
derivbutton.grid(row=0, column=1)
secondderiv = Button(text="Second Derivative")
secondderiv.grid(row=1, column=1)
AnswerLabel = Label(text="Answer")
AnswerLabel.grid(row=2, column=0)
StepsLabel = Label(text="Step-by-Step:")
StepsLabel.grid(row=3, column=0)

WhiteBoard = Canvas(width=525, height=400, bg="white")
drawFunction = WhiteBoard.bind("<B1-Motion>", hold)
drawFunction2 = WhiteBoard.bind("<ButtonRelease-1>", release)
WhiteBoard.grid(row=3, column=2)
ClearButton = Button(width=75, height=3, text="Clear All", bg="white", command=clear_all)
ClearButton.grid(row=4, column=2)
ToolBar1 = Frame()
PencilButton = Button(text="Pencil", bg="grey", width=2, height=2)
PencilButton.grid()
ToolBar1.grid(row=0,column=2)
ToolBar2 = Frame()
ToolBar2.grid(row=1, column=2)


root.mainloop()
```

What I want it to look like:
[MS Paint representation of my GUI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7BMxy.png)

What it actually looks like:
[Actual GUI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hxbjJ.png)

Comment: I would recommend you to read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14947657/3714930). It has valuable information on how to make a layout in Tkinter. Also, you should explicitly define the parent of your widgets. Because you don't, you now put everything in the root window and your Frames are unused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't put everything in the root window, and don't try to solve all of your problems only with `grid` or only with `pack`. Be methodical.

For example, your GUI looks like it's divided into two sections: an area on the left with an equation, some buttons, and the "Answer:" and "Steps" sectons. The area on the right has some buttons and a canvas or text widget. So, start by creating two frames, and use `pack` to put them side by side.

Next, tackle the left frame. It appears to be made of three sections: the equation and some buttons, an answer section, and a steps section. These areas are arranged top-to-bottom. You can either create three frames and arrange them with `pack`, or you could try to arrange them all with `grid`. Either should work, though I would probably make a frame at least for the top section.

Finally, solve the problem on the right. Again, it appears to be made of three sections so three frames would make the job easier: one for the buttons at the top, one for the stuff in the middle, and one for the button on the bottom.

Don't try to lay this all out at once. Just do one section at a time. Give each frame a unique color initially so you can see where one frame ends and the next begins.

Comment: Thank you! I made it work using sticky. Grid and sticky with padx and pady gave me a more flexible layout like the one i was hoping for.