# python tkinter Radiobuttons - both buttons are selected before being displayed

Tags: python, tkinter

I have looked at every posting I can find, but still can't seem to fix the issue. I have a tkinter app and am trying to add radiobuttons. No matter what I try, the buttons come up with both preselected. I'd like them to appear blank.

Please help me. am trying to figure Python out and have been able to handle the screen scraping, logging into a site that tries hard to lock out applications, but can't get this detail straight. Thee code is quite long, but i think i am including the relevant section. The problem area is the last section at the bottom.

Thanks in advance for any help provided.

## Create the User Name/Password Heading Area

```
    self.heading_prompt = tk.Label(self.label_entry_frame, text='LOG `enter code here`on\      `ASSSISTANT')
    self.heading_prompt.config(fg='blue', font('times',heading_font, 'bold'))
    self.heading_prompt.pack(side = 'left')
    self.label_entry_frame.place(x = 112, y=100)

    #   User credentials - prompt
    self.user_name_prompt = tk.Label(self.name_entry_frame, text='Select `enter code here`User:                          ')
    self.user_name_prompt.config(fg='green', font=('times', ``regular_font, 'bold'))
    self.user_name_prompt.pack(side = 'left')

    #   Create Course Name Listbox
    self.user_name_selected = tk.Listbox(self.name_entry_frame,width =7, `enter code here`height = 2, highlightcolor="green",selectmode = 'single', `enter code here`exportselection = "False" )
    self.user_name_selected.config(fg='green', font=enter code here`enter code here`('times',regular_font, 'bold'))
    self.user_name_selected.insert(1, "Margy")
    self.user_name_selected.insert(2, "Steve")
    self.user_name_selected.pack(side = 'left')       
    self.name_entry_frame.place(x=10,y=130)

    #   Position Cursor into User Name Listbox
    self.user_name_selected.focus_set()


    #   User credentials - buttons
    self.user_no = 0
    #self.user_no.set(value = 0)
    user_rb_1 = tk.Radiobutton(self.name_entry_frame, text = "Margy", variable = self.user_no, value = 1)
    user_rb_1.config(fg='green', font=('times',regular_font, 'bold'))
    user_rb_1.pack(side = "left")
    user_rb_2 = tk.Radiobutton(self.name_entry_frame, text = "Steve", variable = self.user_no, value = 1)
    user_rb_2.config(fg='green', font=('times',regular_font, 'bold'))
    user_rb_2.pack(side = "left")
    self.name_entry_frame.place(x=30, y=160)
```

Answer (score 2):

The Radiobutton's `variable` is supposed to be a [tkinter variable](https://web.archive.org/web/20201112025221/https://effbot.org/tkinterbook/variable.htm):

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

user_no = tk.IntVar()

user_rb_1 = tk.Radiobutton(root, text = "Margy", variable = user_no, value = 1)
user_rb_1.pack()
user_rb_2 = tk.Radiobutton(root, text = "Steve", variable = user_no, value = 2)
user_rb_2.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

You can then get the value selected (`1` or `2`) whenever you want with `user_no.get()`. As long as nothing's selected it will be `0`.

Comment: Thanks so much. Seems so easy when i see it, but the lack of documentation and code that is posted that is wrong is overwhelming. Not sure how i vote your answer up (this is my first question), but a big thumbs up from me. Now i have to figure out how to stack them vs. side by side and I'll be cooking. If you have an idea great - also let me know if there is something i can do to acknowledge your answer. Thank you so very much!

Comment: As for placement of widgets, you should look into both [`pack`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/pack.htm) and [`grid`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/grid.htm). Both have their use cases, and it's possible to use them both in one app, as long as you *do not* use both in the same container. For reasoning behind how to make your layout, I really like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14947657/3714930). As for what to do when you get an answer on your question, there's a [help page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) for that. Good luck!

Comment: Pretty sure i got it figured out. Need to place the two radio buttons in separate frames and then locate them (I am using place) where i wanted. Kept looking at it like there was some option in tkinter that would do it for me...Not thinking clearly.  Thanks again...

Comment: Honestly,  `place` almost never is the best solution. With `pack` and `grid` you can make almost anything you want. If you can't figure it out, you could of course always ask a new question.