# Button Adjusting tkinter Python 3.8

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

all of my code is ready except the placement of the Quit button. I want to move to the Calculate button as much as possible, even like sticked to each other. Could you help in adjusting so the buttons will stick to each other?

```
from tkinter import *

window = Tk()


class MainGUI:
    def __init__(self):
        Label(window, text="Enter the property value: $").grid(row=1,column=1, sticky=W)
        Label(window, text="Assessment Value").grid(row=2,column=1, sticky=W)
        Label(window, text="Property Tax").grid(row=3,column=1, sticky=W)

        self.propertyValue = StringVar()
        self.assessmentValue = StringVar()
        self.propertyTax = StringVar()

        Entry(window, textvariable=self.propertyValue,justify=RIGHT).grid(row=1, column=2)

        Button(window, text="Calculate",
               command=self.calculate).grid(row=6, column=1, sticky=E)
        Button(window, text="Quit",
               command=self.close_window).grid(row=6, column=2, sticky=E)

        Label(window, textvariable=
        self.assessmentValue).grid(row=2, column=2, sticky=E)
        Label(window, textvariable=
        self.propertyTax).grid(row=3, column=2, sticky=E)

        window.mainloop()  # Create an event loop

    def calculate(self):
        self.assessmentValue.set("{0:10.2f}".format(float(self.propertyValue.get()) * 60 / 100))
        self.propertyTax.set("{0:10.2f}".format(float(self.propertyValue.get()) * 60 / 10000 * 0.75))

    def close_window(self):
        window.destroy()


MainGUI()
```

Comment: `Button(window, text="Quit",command=self.close_window).grid(row=6, column=2, sticky=W)`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Tkinter Grid: How to position widgets so they are not stuck together](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14946963/tkinter-grid-how-to-position-widgets-so-they-are-not-stuck-together)

Comment: https://effbot.org/tkinterbook/grid.htm is a great resource for the grid manager, and a pretty good tkinter resource overall.

Comment: Suggest to set `sticky=W+E` for both buttons.